# Export features from an ArcGIS Online layer?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I'm trying to do something extremely basic: create a layer of selected counties across the USA by joining a table (indexed by FIPS code) with a national shapefile of counties.

I figured this would be a good use case for the ArcGIS Online portal, so I found a counties layer, added it, and performed the join. But all of the normal methods I'd use to export the selected counties to a geodatabase or shapefile are all greyed out. Is there any way to do this with online data, or do I have to go download my own shapefile of counties?

Comment: What do you mean by "I found a counties layer"? If you found the layer by searching ArcGIS Online (for example, maybe you found the Living Atlas USA Counties layer), you won't be able to export the joined data because you don't own the counties data that was an input to the join operation.