# ArcGIS Online - problem with export (backup) the layer by saving it in specified GIS format

Tags: export, arcgis-online, feature-layer, arcgis-online-webmap

I have the layer uploaded to ArcGIS Online as you can see below.

[image]

I am wondering how to export the existing layer or new layer to various GIS format.

Maybe the question is silly, although it's the repercussion of service updates and so on.

All the stuff I found refers to hints, which seem to be not valid anymore.

[https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011795#:~:text=an%20organization](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011795#:%7E:text=an%20organization))%3A-,In%20ArcGIS%20Online%2C%20navigate%20to%20the%20Content%20page.,an%20item%20in%20My%20Content.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWk_qnguGks&ab_channel=EsriIndustries

because the interface shown there doesn't match my interface after login in at all.

Moreover, it looks like I am not the only one, who faces a problem like this, furthermore, the situation seems to be new.

[Export features from an ArcGIS Online layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404978/export-features-from-an-arcgis-online-layer)

The edit options have been also changed

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvKqQ4j5gh4&ab_channel=ReneRubalcava

there is no option for add new field to the exsiting data attribute layer.

From the options we currently have, I can only:

- Open the map in ArcGIS desktop (by downloading the .pkinfo files for ArcMap and .pitemx files for ArcGIS Pro)
- Share map or embed it
- Save the map or layer virtually in my folder profile

[image]

There is no option to export the file i.e in GeoJSON at all despite all the sources available in Google Search point out explicitly, that the option exists!
Has ESRI changed something over the last few weeks? The Youtube tutorial attached is just 3 months old.

The same situation applies to New Map Viewer mode.

Could anyone advise how to get the interface as shown in this article?
https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/data-hosting/tutorials/tools/create-a-new-feature-layer/

Does anyone know how to export something from ArcGIS Online map to the hard drive?

Comment: The "random" in your title is confusing, since you really mean a specific format.

Comment: OK I changed the title.

Comment: The documentation you shared that you would like to replicate is for ArcGIS Developers Account.
How have you uploaded the layer to ArcGIS Online, and if published did you checked if you get the download option in the item details page of the layer.

Comment: I just logged into the ArcGIS Online and created the map. Next I've uploaded the geojson layer.
https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=269ac3059e254da78deb33f793b133db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit your question to say you are using a free ArcGIS public account. You can [export data](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/use-hosted-layers.htm#GUID-47A1D795-B330-45D7-89F7-9203A99E6924) from a hosted feature layer if one of the following is true:

> - You own the features.
> - You are an administrator for your ArcGIS Online
>   organization.
> - You aren't the hosted feature layer owner or the
>   administrator, but the owner or administrator has configured the
>   hosted feature layer to allow others to export the data. This setting
>   can be changed on the item page Settings tab by checking the Allow
>   others to export to different formats check box under Export Data.

I created a public account just now. However, I also have a named user license account. So, to test I went into the settings of a layer in my named user account and checked Export Data.

[image]

Without doing this from the named user account I was seeing what you are seeing in your second image. Only after did I see the ability to Export Data from my public account.

[image]

Comment: Can you have it for the free version? As far as I am concerned it applies to the premium subscription.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can? I have a named user license (edited my answer). How do you get a free version? If I google 'ArcGIS free version' I get a bunch of third-party results.

Comment: The free version can be set by singing in only without any purchase plan.

Comment: I edited my answer to better fit your question.